# Memory keeps growing

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, poco-libraries

I'm pretty sure that this Poco part of the library is not leaking, but also I can't figure it out why the memory keeps increasing.

If I let this program to run for half a minute, the ram memory increase by more than 10MB, starting from less than one.

```
#include "Poco/Net/SSLManager.h"
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < 1000000)
        {
            Poco::Net::Context::Ptr context = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_NONE, 9, false, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
            counter++;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I set a breakpoint to see if the object is deleted and it does;

```
inline void RefCountedObject::release() const
{
    if (--_counter == 0) delete this;
}
```

The code above is from *class Foundation_API RefCountedObject* which is used by the context.

I spent almost two days trying to understand why the memory keeps increasing.
Testing with Valgrind, it says that it does leak memory, but nobody mention about this on the internet.

Compiled and run on Ubuntu and Mac os x too, the same problem.

Thank you.

**Later edit:**
By running *valgrind --leak-check=yes ./exec* on mac os x, below is the output:

```
==808== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==808== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==808== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==808== Command: ./exec
==808== 
--808-- ./exec:
--808-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
--808-- /Users/myusername/bla/local/blaStream/blaStream/Libraries/libjson_linux-gcc-4.2.1_libmt.dylib:
--808-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
--808-- /Users/myusername/bla/local/blaStream/blaStream/Libraries/libboost_system-mt.dylib:
--808-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
--808-- /Users/myusername/bla/local/blaStream/blaStream/Libraries/libboost_thread-mt.dylib:
--808-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
UNKNOWN __pthread_sigmask is unsupported. This warning will not be repeated.
==808== 
==808== HEAP SUMMARY:
==808==     in use at exit: 72,981 bytes in 1,029 blocks
==808==   total heap usage: 305,673 allocs, 304,644 frees, 11,304,653 bytes allocated
==808== 
==808== 72 (32 direct, 40 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 73 of 131
==808==    at 0x47F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:300)
==808==    by 0x8294F3: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x80BEDB: sk_new_null (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x81EE87: engine_cleanup_add_last (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x7FFD4E: ENGINE_add (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x87FF55: ENGINE_load_dynamic (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x83180C: OPENSSL_config (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x1152669: Poco::Crypto::OpenSSLInitializer::initialize() (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoCrypto.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0xFC6DE: Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoNetSSL.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0xFC67F: Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoNetSSL.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0x100027ADB: main (in ./exec)
==808== 
==808== 904 (176 direct, 728 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 100 of 131
==808==    at 0x47F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:300)
==808==    by 0x8294F3: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x825CE5: lh_new (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x83AAC2: def_get_class (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x83A4E8: int_new_ex_data (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x81EBFE: ENGINE_new (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x87FEBA: ENGINE_load_dynamic (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x83180C: OPENSSL_config (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x1152669: Poco::Crypto::OpenSSLInitializer::initialize() (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoCrypto.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0xFC6DE: Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoNetSSL.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0xFC67F: Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoNetSSL.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0x100027ADB: main (in ./exec)
==808== 
==808== 1,536 (176 direct, 1,360 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 119 of 131
==808==    at 0x47F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:300)
==808==    by 0x8294F3: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x825CE5: lh_new (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x87E33D: int_thread_get (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x87E54A: int_thread_set_item (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x87DE34: ERR_get_state (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x85DF4B: ERR_clear_error (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x83180C: OPENSSL_config (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x1152669: Poco::Crypto::OpenSSLInitializer::initialize() (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoCrypto.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0xFC6DE: Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoNetSSL.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0xFC67F: Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoNetSSL.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0x100027ADB: main (in ./exec)
==808== 
==808== 2,048 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 120 of 131
==808==    at 0x51C7: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:627)
==808==    by 0xC9100A: strerror (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==808==    by 0x853C87: ERR_load_ERR_strings (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x872388: ERR_load_crypto_strings (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x7C5DC8: SSL_load_error_strings (in /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x1152673: Poco::Crypto::OpenSSLInitializer::initialize() (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoCrypto.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0xFC6DE: Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoNetSSL.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0xFC67F: Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoNetSSL.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0x100027ADB: main (in ./exec)
==808== 
==808== 21,728 (32 direct, 21,696 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 131 of 131
==808==    at 0x47F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:300)
==808==    by 0x8294F3: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x80BEDB: sk_new_null (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x867092: CONF_module_add (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x82C5C8: OPENSSL_load_builtin_modules (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x831807: OPENSSL_config (in /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib)
==808==    by 0x1152669: Poco::Crypto::OpenSSLInitializer::initialize() (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoCrypto.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0xFC6DE: Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoNetSSL.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0xFC67F: Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/local/Cellar/poco/1.4.6p4-all/lib/libPocoNetSSL.16.dylib)
==808==    by 0x100027ADB: main (in ./exec)
==808== 
==808== LEAK SUMMARY:
==808==    definitely lost: 2,464 bytes in 5 blocks
==808==    indirectly lost: 33,184 bytes in 639 blocks
==808==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==808==    still reachable: 264 bytes in 3 blocks
==808==         suppressed: 37,069 bytes in 382 blocks
==808== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
```

Comment: if you are using C++, auto_ptr<> should do your job correctly (unique_ptr<> in C++11)?

Comment: valgrind should be able to tell you where the leaked memory was allocated.  Judging by the code you posted though, it may be a library issue.  If you remove the counter increment so it simply runs forever, does it continue to grow forever?  Some libraries internally use static state which is allocated dynamically but never freed (this behavior causes lots of false positives in leak checkers, perhaps this is what you're seeing?)

Comment: @hagubear : I tried with auto_ptr<> and also with shared_ptr from boost, but it is the same.

Comment: @MartinFuller     in the 2nd code snippet, do you mean `if(--counter == 0) delete this;`? because you are using `--_counter == 0`

Comment: @hagubear Nop, it is not written by me. That is a snippet from the header from the source code inside the Poco library, and it is ok with the underscore.

Comment: @Wug Please have a look at the initial question, I edited to include the output from Valgrind. For the output added, I reduced the "while counter < 100" inside the code(I also tried with while(true) and then killed the program: the result is the same). Yes, I think that it grows until the system will crash. The most I let it to reach, was almost 200MB.

Comment: @par It gives me a syntax error: "Ambiguous converstion of delete expression of type 'Poco::Net::Context::Ptr'(aka 'AutoPtr<Poco::Net::Context>') to a pointer".  Although I can call "release()", the issue remain the same. Beside, I should not delete/release explicitly, because it is supposed (and it seems to do so) to delete automatically.

Comment: My guess is that it's a library issue, though I don't see the suspect blocks in the valgrind output (all of valgrind's "definitely lost" blocks look like the sort I mentioned earlier, they're all allocated in the same initialize function).  @par: I'm pretty sure he's mentioned that `Poco::Net::Context::Ptr` is not a raw pointer, but a reference counting wrapper.

Comment: @MartinFuller: try this. Outside of that loop, allocate another context, and keep it around until the end of the program.  Rerun your memory assessment and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Wug From what I see, it's the same.

Comment: Hard to say.  I recommend not creating hundreds of thousands of contexts, and maybe filing a bug for the library maintainers to try to make sense of.  Did you read all of the documentation? Maybe there's some intended behavior you're not considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely due to [this issue](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/612); [fix](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/commit/03deea59c5b1276f012968395640b6b472250f0b) will be in 1.6.0